# Export runnable program from python in eclipse on windows

Tags: python, windows, export

I did some research. (Sorry, really new a this) I need to create an exe for python 2.7. I am running python through eclipse on windows 8. I have tried py2exe and pyinstaller. I've gotten as far as downloading them but I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: It's runnable as python on any system that has python installed on it. Are you looking to export an EXE?

Comment: I am looking to export an EXE.

Comment: Then look at [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) and [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

Answer (score 0):

For a standalone and portable executable, you can have a look at [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)